# How can I prevent user from installing old version of APK?

Tags: android, installation, version

When we are using version code in android manifest.

When user have new version apk installed,How can I prevent user from installing previous version's apk?

Or at least give him some hint like "You are using an old version of the app to overwite the new version "?

Answer (score 1):

***User cannot install two versions of application at same time.***  So don't worry about prevention.

Although this is possible by ADB but that replaces the previous app with new one.

Comment: I'm worrying about that I can install the old version apk when the new version is installed.I have done it manually by click the apk file in the file manager.

Comment: thats what I am saying.. but you will get only one version of application in device.. check again... user can manually install any version of application (BUT KEEP IN MIND that device will have single version of your app). But Play gives feature to install only latest version of application... User can't install older version of application from PLay...

Comment: So what is your confusion... your app is going to be installed via Play.. right?

Comment: I want to warn my user from installing old version on top of new version.Maybe there's not a mechanism to do that?

Comment: Where your application will be? Are you not going to upload on PLay?

Comment: I will not upload it to the google play because it is an app for certain company employees using.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install older version application on a newer application. Android will not allow you to do this. So don't worry about his.

Comment: I'm doing a test and this action is not prevent by system.First I export an apk named app1.0.apk with versionCode 1 and versionName 1.0.Then export an apk named app2.0.apk with versionCode 2 ande versionName 2.0.With 2.0 installed,I can still install 1.0 on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the app version when the application starts, then compare it to a version provided by a server, you can simply store it on a txt or json on the backend server, then when the app starts, you can compare both versions. If the app version is lower than the reported by the server warn the user with a message and a link to the new apk, or block the usage of the app.

You can get the app code or version in Android like this:

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

...

final PackageManager packageManager = this.reactContext.getPackageManager();
final String packageName = this.reactContext.getPackageName();

try {
    String version = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionName;
    String buildNumber = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName, 0).versionCode;
catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    // Handle error
}
```